# JavaLite, get TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g, timestamp-with-timezone

In my final study project, I am using Javalite/ActiveJDBC to get information in a DB.
In my table `Users`, I have a colum with the type as `TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE` (example value `15-10-30 12:32:37.366954000 -04:00`).

When I call the model for this table I cannot get the time. I also need to convert it to a string.

My model:

```
import org.javalite.activejdbc.Model;
import org.javalite.activejdbc.annotations.DbName;
import org.javalite.activejdbc.annotations.Table;

/**
 *
 * @author mrabia
 */
@DbName("myDB")
@Table("USERS")
public class Users extends Model{ }
```

In my webservice:

```
class getUserInfos () {
    .......
    Users.getTimestamp("CREATED_DATE");

    ...
}
```

Comment: "help me please!" questions are never well recieved. Consider reading this to better understand how you should ask good questions to get the answer you're looking for http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but your code is not correct. The getter methods on models are instance methods, not statics, so your code should not compile.

To answer your question, you could do this:

```
List<User> users  = Users.where("status = ? ", "active");
TimeStamp ts = users.getTimestamp("CREATED_DATE");
```

Additionally you need to add tags to your questions for people to get notifications. In this case two tags: 'activejdbc' and 'javalite'